# Give element height and remove it after

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, height

I am using [Easy Pagination plugin](http://cssglobe.com/post/9801/easy-paginate-jquery-plugin-for-pagination) to paginate some content. The problem is that after clicking 'next', the browser jumps up do to the height of the element loading data for Pagination.

I am trying to fetch the height of the element, example `.recent`, and give it to `.recent` before clicking `.next` (Before the pagination happens), then set it after.

So I am wondering how can I set the height of .recent, and then take off?

Here is what I tried so far:

```
  var recentH = $('.recent').height();

 $('.next').click(function(){
      $('.recent').css( 'height', recentH );
 });
```

Comment: Thank you MGA, sorry I am tired.....

Comment: heres example: sorry, site is for client and stil working on it... http://kdevs.site40.net/ click 'next'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to fetch the height of the element

`$.height()` or `$.css('height')` is what you´re looking for, they both get and set values. See [height()](http://api.jquery.com/height/) and [css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/).

*"The difference between .css('height') and .height() is that the latter returns a unit-less pixel value (for example, 400) while the former returns a value with units intact (for example, 400px)"*

> before clicking .next (Before the pagination happens), then set it after.

Are you using some plugin for the pagination and does it have it´s own click event handler for the `.next` element?

Notice that your selectors matches elements by their CSS class and that there might be multiple elements. You should therefore specify the element to read the height of.

Short example;

```
$('.next').click(function(){
  var height = $('#firstElement').height();
  // Pagination actions here (toggling elements)
  $('#secondElement').css(height + 'px');
});
```

Comment: Yes, I linked to the plugin and also in the comment I provided an example of what I am working on. Click 'next'.

Answer (score 0):

After seeing the example I figured this might help:

```
var h = $('.recent').height();

$('.next').click(function(){
  $('.recent').css({ 'height': h + 'px', 'display': 'block' });
});
```